# Cannot Update string property using CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

My application uses a custom numeric keypad to fill my textboxes. Here's my xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="{Binding MyText}">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding KeyPad}" CommandParameter="{Binding MyText}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

MyText is a string ViewModel Property and KeyPad is a RelayCommand

In my ViewModel:

```
    public string MyText { get => _myText; set => SetProperty(ref _myText, value); }
    public RelayCommand KeyPad { get => _kpUnitField; set => _kpUnitField = value; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        KeyPad = new RelayCommand(execute => KeyPad_Callback(execute), canExecute => true);
    }
```

The KeyPad_Callback function calls the keypad window, INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented and the View - ViewModel communication for everything else works just fine.

My problem is that the TextBox is not updated. If a change the CommandParameter to bind the ElementName:

```
<MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick" Command="{Binding KeyPad}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=myTextBox}"/>
```

It updates the TextBox but not the property.

It's my very first post here. Usually all my doubts are answered with questions already asked. Sorry if I was not clear enough.

**EDIT**

As Ed Plunket asked here's de KeyPad_Callback:

```
    private void KeyPad_Callback(object parameter) 
    {
        var keyPad = new NumKeyPad(parameter) // It's a window class that receives a string as argument 
        var retVal = keyPad.ShowDialog();
        if(retval == true)
        {
            parameter = keyPad.Result; //Result is a string Property
        }
    }
```

**EDIT - WORKAROUND**
According to this
[tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1669331](http://tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1669331)

the problem is the way strings works. A class wrapper could solve it.

So I make a simple `Field` class so I can group the Label and TextBox strings of the field and I pass this class in the CommandParameter argument. Now it's "working".

If someone finds out a way to work directly with strings I would appreciate, but for now just thanks to everyone for the answers.

Comment: You have a command parameter, but your RelayCommand is not set to take a parameter. Shouldn't you be creating a RelayCommand<object>() so the parameter MyText can be passed to the function?

Comment: The execute parameter of RelayCommand is Action<object>. The KeyPad_Callback(object parameter) function gets MyText just fine.

Comment: @RodrigoMartins Can you show us the code for `KeyPad_Callback`? I'd like to see exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Why are you even passing the value of the MyText property as a command argument? You have access to this property in the very same view model where the command is defined...

Comment: mm8 the code is just a simplified version of my code. The view is like a form with more textboxes that uses that structure. So I have to pass it to know which one is going to be modified.

Comment: Thanks for KeyPad_Callback. That's what I thought you might be doing. It's not a matter of how strings work. It's how parameters are passed, and how bindings work. The solution you found is the only good one: Write a Field class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Then you can expose it on the parent viewmodel, bind to its properties in XAML, and you can also pass a Field as a CommandParameter.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to do the following:

1. Your ViewModel should inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged or BindableBase which I see you did because of this line
   `SetProperty(ref _myText, value);`
2. `Text="{Binding MyText}"` should be changed to 
   `Text="{Binding MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`
3. If you need 2 way binding then it should be
   `Text="{Binding MyText,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Read Kevin Cook's feedback as well.

Comment: 2. That's good practice, but not relevant to the source updating the target as in this case. 3. Any binding on that property is two-way by default in WPF.

Comment: I found this http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1669331. Explains but dont solves

Comment: @RodrigoMartins After looking at that link I think I know what you're trying to achieve - in your `KeyPad_Callback(object parameter) ` you assign some string to `parameter` and expect the assigned value to be populated back to `MyText` property through the `CommandParameter` binding. If that's the case, then I'm afraid it's not possible.